# SQL Query Performance in case of simple union

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, view, union

I have a simple query tuning question, it is

can We improve the performance of a view which have definition as

`SELECT * FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B`

and this is performing so poorly that it is taking 12 seconds for 6.5k Records

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use Left Outer Joiun.It will Give you a fall in Time and good in performance.

Comment: @UpvoteMarkAnswer: That will give me records from only left table, and more over suppose that i can't change this query,

Comment: How long does select * from A take? How long does select * from B take? Are the datatypes similar in A and B (no implicit casting happening)?

Comment: Are the columns in both tables identical i.e. same order, type and size?  Also it is a bit dangerous using a wildcard select in a view, because if someone updates one table by adding a column the view would break due to the mismatch in the number of columns.  However if you explicitly select the columns the view will keep on working.

Comment: @zfus  SELECT * FROM A is taking all time. i.e. 12 seconds

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  Probably missing indices.  However, given your last comment, are you missing keys/indices in general?

Comment: Perform Execute Plan on `select * from a` and see what why so much time is spent in table a. If an index scan is happening, [check index fragmentation](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/03/27/sql-server-2005-find-index-fragmentation-details-slow-index-performance/) and rebuild index if possible (assumption: you are using SQL Server).

Comment: @user2480596 , you are right the table does not have any index, but will index be refereed if i am just using Union all.?

Comment: Okay ! I assume that i can't improve this queries performance is there any other way to get the output of Union all ??

Comment: Which DBMS? Also, give an example of the where clause you're using with the view.

Comment: @Bohemian Its SQL Server 2008 R2, It does not have any where clause i want all data from both tables.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with a `union` view like that is that the original columns of the tables are not accessible to the optimizer via the view, so when you *use* the view like this:

```
select * from myview where foo = 5
```

the where clause is a *filter* on the *entire* rowset delivered by the view, so *all* the rows from both tables are processed *after* the union, so no indexes will be used.

To have any hope at performance, you have to somehow get the condition you want *inside* the view and applied to *each* table, but keep it variable so you can apply different criteria when you use it.

I found a work-around that does this. It's a little bit hacky, and doesn't work for concurrent use, but it works! Try this:

```
 create table myview_criteria(val int);
 insert into myview_criteria values (0); -- it should have exactly one row

 create view myview as
 SELECT * FROM A
 WHERE foo = (select val from myview_criteria)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM B
 WHERE foo = (select val from myview_criteria);
```

then to use it:

```
update myview_criteria set val = 5;
select * from myview;
```

Assuming there's an index on `foo`, that index will be used.

Caution here, because obviously this technique won't work when multiple executions are done concurrently.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a (Inline) Table-Valued Function, instead?

Comment: @TomLint could be, but this works for any database (most of which don’t have such things as table-valued functions)

Answer (score 1):

is there a reason u keep these two not in the same table, no matter what you do, eventually it will be horrible. If possible consider a migration to one table. If not, you can always "materialize a view" by inserting them all into the same thing.

---

with that being said, you are not going to be selecting * on a union, if there are specific conditions on top of the view, performance can be improve by the indexing that column.

It would help if you tell everyone what specific db this is for.

Answer (score 0):

My best advice is to limit the number or records that are returned from the source tables to only what you really need and making sure your data is properly indexed.

Don't use * unless its an ad-hoc script (even then it would still be better to list the columns) include only the columns that you really need for the task at hand.

Use proper indexes based on the most frequently used queries. Remove any unused indexes. Remove any duplicate indexes.

Pluralsight has a wonderful course on MS SQL Server query performance tuning. 
http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/query-tuning-introduction

The course is presented by Vinod Kumar and Pinal Dave who are two very brilliant individuals.

You could also check out Pinal's article on SQL Server Performance to help point out areas that you may not have thought about.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/sql-server-performance-tuning/